# User usability analysis

Tags: usability-study, methodology

i am unable to find the answers to the following questions.Please help me resolve

- (a) Name quantitative and qualitative techniques for analysing the usability of a software product.
- (b) Compare the costs and beneﬁts of the quantitative techniques.
- (c) Compare the costs and beneﬁts of the qualitative techniques.
- (d) If restricted to a single one of these techniques when designing a new online
  banking system, which would you choose and why?

Comment: Why are you unable to find the answers at least to a, b and c? There is a mountain of information available on the web and in books. This question just seems to ask us to do the googling for you? The scope of the question is too broad.

Comment: there are many techniques but which are quantitative or qualitative how would know

Comment: Because the quantitative looks at metrics: absolutes that say this or that is better - that prove something - often used when comparing two comparable products or versions of a system, where as qualitative is about getting feedback to improve the system. Quantitative is about measuring the system so has less user input (because all users are different), qualitative is about getting feedback from real people.

Comment: no man no homework

Answer (score 4):

What you need is to read this fabulous book: http://www.measuringux.com/index.htm

[image]